# Programatical exponential congruency solver

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Is there a way to programatically solve exponential congruencies?

```
a^x ≡ b(mod m)
```

I have seen few [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrKfSyTuuhs) on how to solve those manually, but I am unable to find solutions that could be implemented in C or C++ on very large numbers. I have taken a look into the arbitrary precision libraries in boost or so, but I have not seen functions for this purpose. Even in MatLab I have seen only solution for [linear congruence](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/56889-solvecongruence-a-c-m).

**Is there a way to solve the above for X in a programatical manner? (Would be nice to have it in a fast way, but that is optional at the first step.)**

Comment: Essential keyword: **"discrete logarithm"**

Comment: For what its worth, it is precisely *because* this is a difficult problem that several cryptoalgorithms are secure.

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you for pointing me to at least to a direction. As I have seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm it is indeed a hard problem, I feel like the base of the library of babel  (https://libraryofbabel.info/) should be this. The reversableness is exactly this problem is not it?

Comment: Yes, your issue is exactly the discrete logarithm issue.

Comment: I have found this description: https://github.com/librarianofbabel/libraryofbabel.info-algo I am not sure if this is the actual site, nor that the described behaviour is truely working. Any comment on that @JeanMarie? Thank you for the insights, I am just curious :)